# jQuery not calling form .submit() when using Ajax on IE

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery plugin that does some magic during the `.submit` of a form (creates a hidden string and writes it to an `<input type="hidden">` item). On IE this works well if I submit the form via POST, but if I use Ajax, then the `.submit` callback is never called. Here is an example of the flow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (jQuery) {
        jQuery.fn.createHidden = function () {
            // 1. What I want to have called
            $(this).submit(function () {
                var hiddenText = $(document.createElement('input'));
                hiddenText.attr('name', 'hidden');
                hiddenText.attr('type', 'hidden');
                hiddenText.val('1');
                $(this).append(hiddenText);
                alert("1");
            });
            // 2. What I came up with as a workaround
            $(this).parents('div.FormWrapper').submit(function () {
                var form = this.children('form');
                if (form && form.tagName == "FORM") {
                    var hiddenText = $(document.createElement('input'));
                    hiddenText.attr('name', 'hidden');
                    hiddenText.attr('type', 'hidden');
                    hiddenText.val('2');
                    $(form).append(hiddenText);
                    alert("2");
                }
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".form").createHidden();
    });
</script>

<div class="FormWrapper">
@*using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", @id = "form" }))*@
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("About", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myReply", HttpMethod = "post" }, new { @class = "form", @id = "form" }))
{
    <div class="ExposedData">
        @Html.TextBox("data", "", new { @class = "data" })
        <input type="submit" value="Button" />
        <span id="myReply"></span>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

```
// MVC HomeController.cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public string About(string hidden)
    {
        return hidden;
    }
}
```

When using Http POST on IE, I see alerts 1 & 2, but when using Ajax I only see alert 2. Firefox only shows 1. Chrome, Safari and Opera show 1 & 2.

Is there a better way of fixing this so it works on all browsers? Could this be related to the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` I'm using in MVC3?

I've tried `$('form').ajaxStart()`, `AjaxOptions{OnBegin=...}`, `<form onsubmit=...>` but they didn't do the trick as most get called **after** the controller is visited, and hence the hiddenText is not included in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the [jQuery froms plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) - works in all browsers.

And maybe get rid of the idea that a form has to submit, AJAX requires no forms.

Hidden inputs inside forms are not really recommend, can be easily manipulated.

Edit:

Including a plug-in into a plug-in is probably not the best way...

I'd rather recommend to use the native $.ajax function,
here's a real-world example I just wrote:

```
$('li.sheet').unbind().bind('click', function() {
    $.id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($(this).next('div.edit').length == 0){
        $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_handler.php?mode=form&sheet='+$.id,
                success:function(r){
                    $('li#'+$.id).after(r);
                    $('li#'+$.id).next('div.edit').toggle(200);
                }
        });
    }
    else {
        $(this).next('div.edit').toggle(200, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The forms plugin worked and fixed my problem. I added "$(this).ajaxSubmit({ target: '#myReply' });" just before alert("1") in the code above, and switched to the Html.BeginForm function instead of Ajax.BeginForm. -- Thanks!!

Comment: I see what you mean. I was hoping I wouldn't have to touch the plugin since it is not mine. The code above is just an illustration of what the plugin does. I felt that adding one or two lines of code to it was OK, however, at the end I decided you were right and followed your advice on calling .ajax directly, and in the process removed the hidden text altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is include more data in the ajax request then I recommend using the data paremeter:

```
$.ajax(...,
       data: {
           hidden: function() { ...build string here...  } 
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second alert comes from trying to catch a submit event on a div. That is definitely going to be a weird, inconsistent event.

What could be happening is that your createHidden is being attached to the form after the unobtrusive-ajax is being attached. So, when you submit, it'll call unobtrusive-ajax first, which most likely stops propagation of the event to other functions.

Try taking of unobtrusive-ajax and submitting again, see if your function fires. If so, you'll have to try to figure out how to attach createHidden first or use something other than unobtrusive-ajax.

Comment: I think your observation about event propagation in jquery might be the cause. I debugged the creation of events inside jquery, and submit is one before the last in the queue (when not using Ajax). I couldn't figure out how to force the submit event up the queue, so I went with your second suggestion. syslogic's advice to try the forms plugin actually did the trick. -- thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping I would find a way of using `Ajax.BeginForm()` and not have to touch the external plugin I'm using, but at the end I followed the advice given, and this is what came out of it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.form').createHidden();
        $('.form').unbind('submit.plugin').bind('submit.mything', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/About',
                data: { hidden: $('.form').getHidden() },
                success: function (reply) { $('#myReply').html(reply); }
            });
        });
    });

    (function (jQuery) {
        jQuery.fn.createHidden = function () {
            jQuery.fn.getHidden = function () {
                return 'message';
            };
            $(this).bind('submit.plugin', function () {
                // let it do whatever it does...
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", @id = "form" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("data", "", new { @class = "data" })
    <input type="submit" value="Button" />
}
<div id="myReply"></div>
```